# android frame animation of buttons in gridview

Tags: android, animation, gridview, button, resources

i have made one of these tap number games for android as a test project and for this i have made a gridview with about 20 buttons in it. when one of these buttons is pressed an animation is started. this runs fine for the first few times but than becomes slower and starts stuttering.

i assume it has something to do with the animation ressource as i use it several times at the same time but i dont know how to solve the problem. 
as i want to remove the button from the gridview when the animation ends i wrapped the AnimationDrawable class to be able to set a Handler which is called at the end of the animation.

```
public void animate() {     
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanimation);
    final AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) getBackground(); 
    final BetterAnimationDrawable better = new BetterAnimationDrawable(anim);
    better.setEndHandler(new EndHandler());
    better.start();     
}
```

thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
@warpzit: thanks for your answer. it's not a handler for earch click but a handler for each button. the onclick method disables the button (so it can only be pressed once) and then calls animate(). actually theres not much more code i can post, the gridview adapters getView looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {           
        final MySpecialButton sb = new MySpecialButton(getApplicationContext());
        sb.setOnClickListener(new SpecialButtonClickListener());
        return nv;              
    }
```

and the mentioned handler looks like this (its actually not removing the button but changing the background-drawable, sorry for that):

```
private class MySpecialHandler extends Handler {

    public MySpecialHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        final Bitmap bitmapMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aspecialmask);
        final BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapMask);            
        d.setColorFilter([someColor], Mode.MULTIPLY);           
        setBackgroundDrawable(d);                                           
    }       

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a new handler for each click? That gotta hurt... How about making just 1 for each button or something else far smarter (need to see more code to come with other suggestions).